# Can we still play Retribution in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

There used to be an option on Arcade to play the Archives: Retribution game mode.

Is it available any more? Is this just during events? Or can people still create Retribution style custom game modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, like the other annual game modes, this can only be played during the time of year that it is available

Or when the Overwatch team brings it back for a special event

Comment: Other game modes were available in custom games. Not sure about Retribution

Comment: They recently announced that all previous special events will be returning for the Anniversary event starting next week.

Comment: @powerlord can you make that into answer

Comment: @J.Chang The Anniversary event is only going to be around for 3 weeks, then Retribution will be unplayable again.  Actually, I question Blizzard's logic here because their stated reason for not having a bunch of events up at once is because they thought having too many game mode queues would be a problem.

Comment: As a side note, Retribution will only be up on certain days during the Anniversary event.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to information from @SPYBUG96 and @Powerlord for a more complete answer. The Archives: Retribution game mode is available each year during the following events:

- **Archives** - All Archives game modes are available for the full event period (3 weeks)

  - includes Uprising, Retribution, Storm Rising storylines
  - includes Story and All Heroes modes
  - includes Normal, Hard, Expert, Legendary modes
  - includes all related achievements
  - includes option to purchase items with coins from any Archives storyline
- **Anniversary** - Some Archives games modes are available on *some random days* during the full event period (3 weeks)

  - could be any of the above storylines
  - could be Story or All Heroes modes (but seems to be usually Story mode)
  - includes Normal, Hard, Expert, Legendary modes
  - includes achievements for the versions that are *randomly selected for some random days* during the event
  - includes option to purchase items with coins from any Archives storyline

If you want to play Retribution for sure, wait for the Archives event each year. Otherwise you'll have to get lucky during Anniversary for it to randomly cycle (on a daily basis) to the version of Retribution you want.

Comment: During anniversary, the days aren't random.  Monday: Lucioball, Tuesday: Junkenstein's Revenge, Wednesday: Mei's Snowball Offensive, Thursday: Yeti Hunt, Friday: Uprising, Saturday: Retribution, and Sunday: Storm Rising. For the gamemodes with two versions, Story mode is during week 1 and 3, while Endless/All Heroes is during week 2.

Comment: Obviously, the above list changes every year as they add new Archives events, shifting everything by one day.  Blizzard does a blogpost with the schedule at the start of the event.